# Integration of $f(g(x))$ by substitution, "creating" $g'(x) dx$ term, how it works?

Tags: calculus, integration

It is clear to me how to integrate $f(g(x))g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$ by substitution, and why it works.

But sometimes there is no $g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$ term, and we can "create" it artificially. The following method described in Spivak Calculus:

Assume that we want to find
$$\int f(g(x))\,\mathrm dx$$
let
$$u = g(x)$$
$$x = g^{-1}(u)$$
$$\mathrm dx = (g^{-1})'(u)\,\mathrm du$$
then
$$\int f(g(x)) \, \mathrm dx = \int f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)\,\mathrm du$$
This method can not be always applied with success, but sometimes it works pretty good. For example:
$$\int \frac{1 + e^x}{1 - e^x}\,\mathrm dx = \int \frac{1 + u}{1 - u} \frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm du = \int \frac{2}{1 - u} + \frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm du$$
Here $u = e^x, x = ln(u)$ and $\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{u}\,\mathrm du$

The algorithm described before it just convenient symbolic manipulation, and Spivak gives the following explanation why this method always works:
$$\int f(g(x))\,\mathrm dx = \int f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
let
$$u = g(x)$$
$$x = g^{-1}(u)$$
$$\frac{1}{g'(x)} = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(u))} = (g^{-1})'(u)$$
$$\mathrm du = g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
and we get
$$\int f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}g'(x)\,\mathrm dx = \int f(u)(g^{-1})'(u)\,\mathrm du$$
as it was stated before.

It is not clear to me why it is correct to apply substitution at this (the last) step. OK, let $g'(x)\,\mathrm dx = \mathrm du$. But the rest of the expression under integral is $f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}$, not just $f(g(x))$ as in "pure" substitution algorithm.

May be this trick can be explained in more details or in different way?

Comment: Let $F(z) = f(z)\cdot (g^{-1})'(z)$. Then you have $F(g(x))$ for the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is a simple misunderstanding. The expression under the integral is indeed $f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}$, but the integral this expression is under is taken with respect to u, not x, unlike the original. Because $\mathrm du = g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$, this integral $\int f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}\,\mathrm du$ (where u of course equals $g(x)$) is equal to $\int f(g(x))\frac{1}{g'(x)}g'(x)\,\mathrm dx$, which is of course in turn equal to $\int f(g(x))\,\mathrm dx$, our original integral, because the artificial $g'(x)$ terms cancel out.